# Combine 2 json data sets using axios and promises based on condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios, es6-promise

I am using the axios json library to combine 2 datasets based on a condition.

My data:

```
    let main = [
    {
        "title": "iPhone",
        "details": {
            "ID": "ABC123",
            "link": "https://www.apple.com/iphone/",
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "iPad",
        "details": {
            "ID": "XYZ123",
            "link": "https://www.apple.com/ipad/",
        }
    },
    ];

    let data1 = [
    {
        data: [
        {site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
        {site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
        {site: 'google', val1:17, val2:19, val3:11},
        {site: 'bing',   val1:13, val2:15, val3:12},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:69, val2:79, val3:15},
        ],
        gadget: 'iPhone'
    }
    ];

    let data2 = [
    {
        data: [
        {site: 'google', val1:17, val2:51, val3:31},,
        {site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:15, val3:17},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:61, val2:71, val3:15},
        {site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},,
        {site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
        ],
        gadget: 'iPad'
    }
    ];
```

All 3 of them come from json urls. `data1` and `data2` are called based on `gadget`. I am not sure how to join the datasets based on the `gadget` from `data...` and `main`.

This is what I tried:

```
//AXIOS CANCEL TOKENS
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get(main, {
    cancelToken: source.token
})
.then(function(elem) {
    console.log(elem)
    elem.map(d => {
        return new Promise((rev, err) => 
            $.getJSON(data1, gadget => rev ({
                title: d.title,
                details: d.details,
                data: gadget.data
            })))
    }).then(promises => Promise.all(promises))
    .then(rd => rd.reduce((acc, item) => {
                acc.push(item);
                return acc;
              }, []))
    .then(arr => {
        console.log(arr);
    })
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

For starters, I am getting `elem.map(...).then is not a function` as an error. Plus I am also not sure how to join the datasets based on `title` from `main` and `data` from `gadget`.

I want this to be my final result:

```
[
    {
        title: 'iPhone',
        details {
            "ID": "ABC123",
            "link": "https://www.apple.com/iphone/",
        },
        data: [
        {site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
        {site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
        {site: 'google', val1:17, val2:19, val3:11},
        {site: 'bing',   val1:13, val2:15, val3:12},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:69, val2:79, val3:15},
        ],
    }
]
```

and

```
    [
    {
        title: 'iPad',
        details: {
            "ID": "XYZ123",
            "link": "https://www.apple.com/ipad/",
        }
        data: [
        {site: 'google', val1:17, val2:51, val3:31},,
        {site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:15, val3:17},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:61, val2:71, val3:15},
        {site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},,
        {site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
        {site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
        ],
    }
]
```

How do I do this using axios? The data sets can get quite large. Using Axios will be helpful with the async data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
const detailRef = main.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.title] = obj;
    return obj;
}, {})

data1.map((item) => ({data: item.data, ...detailRef[item. gadget]}))
console.log(data1)

data2.map((item) => ({data: item.data, ...detailRef[item. gadget]}))
console.log(data2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to use axios though. The data sets can get quite large. It will be helpful with the async data